# Very Basic R - have a strange vector and want to access an element

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector J.

If I print J, this looks as follows:

```
> print (j)
j 
6
```

Now I want to access only the 6.

I already tried

```
j[1]
```

and

```
j [ ,1]
```

but to no avail.

I know this is really simple, but can someone help me still?

Edit: I guessed J would be a vector because I got it by using tail (k,1) on a vector k. What other type could it be?

Comment: Have you tried doing `typeof(j)`, `is.vector(j)` or `class(j)`?

Comment: Also, what happens when you run `j[1]` or `j[,1]`?

Comment: Have you tried: `j[[1]]`

Comment: Would you please write an answer so I can at least vote for it if stealing your time....I was sitting on my brain apparently....J was already the Integer I was looking vor......Sorry about that...

Comment: Oh did you mean you just want `6` without the `j` above it?

Comment: Jes.....so silly I know....Sorry -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` is just the name associated with the 6.

```
j = c(j=6)
> j
j 
6
```

You can still use `j` as `6` even though it has a name.

```
> j + 6
 j 
12 
> j + 6 ==12
   j 
TRUE
```

You can get rid of the pesky names with:

```
> names(j) = NULL
> j
[1] 6
```